# Снова ЧПУ .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, чпу

Всем привет,
хочу сделать из такой ссылки
http://site.ru/index.php?post=11211
такую
http://site.ru/11211

У меня работает такой вариант

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} post=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^$ /post/%1? [R=301]
RewriteRule ^post/([^/]*)$ /?post=$1&xxx=1 [L]
```

но он делает такую ссылку
http://site.ru/post/11211
Если резать post, то он сервер вылетает 500 ошибка

если резать до id, работает этот вариант:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?post=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?post=$1
```

но как сделать так, чтобы при  заходе был редирект с http://site.ru/index.php?post=11211 на такой http://site.ru/11211

Comment: Сделал так 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]


#Перенаправление с динамичных страниц на статичные
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} post=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^$ /post/%1? [R=301]
RewriteRule ^post/([^/]*)$ /?post=$1&xxx=1 [L]

#Перенаправление с динамичных категорий на статичные
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cat=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^$ /cat/%1? [R=301]
RewriteRule ^cat/([^/]*)$ /?cat=$1&xxx=1 [L]

Comment: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} pub=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^$ /%1? [R=301]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?pub=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?pub=$1

итого мы имеем три ссылки 
site.ru/cat/12123
site.ru/post/12123
и site.ru/123 - статичные страницы

видимо сильно торможу, но когда делаешь для каждой разновидности ссылок, он вылетает в ошибку сервера.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А так пробовали?

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ /index.php?post=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: да, работает, спасибо